# Operation Not Permitted in SBT / Typesafe Activator inside Vagrant Synced Folder

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, vagrant, typesafe-activator

I'm running SBT through the Typesafe Activator on an Ubuntu machine provisioned by Vagrant / Virtualbox. The host machine is Windows 8.

I'm trying to compile a Play project https://github.com/markisus/ScalaPoker by entering the commands `./activator` (or `sudo ./activator`) and then `compile` after cloning the repo on to the machine. **The repo is inside a synced folder**. I think this is the root of the problem.

I get the error `Operation not permitted` in:

```
[info] Compiling 34 Scala sources to /home/vagrant/sp2/ScalaPoker/ScalaPokerEngine/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] Operation not permitted
[error] one error found
[error] (ScalaPokerEngine/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 91 s, completed Jan 26, 2015 4:29:22 AM
```

I'm not sure which operation exactly is not permitted. The project compiles fine on my host machine.

Running `last`, I get

```
[debug] Running cached compiler e13c8f, interfacing (CompilerInterface) with Scala compiler version 2.11.1
[debug] Calling Scala compiler with arguments  (CompilerInterface):
[debug]         -bootclasspath
[debug]         /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/netx.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/classes:/root/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar
[debug]         -classpath
[debug]         /home/vagrant/sp2/ScalaPoker/ScalaPokerEngine/target/scala-2.11/classes
[error] Operation not permitted
[error] one error found
[debug] Compilation failed (CompilerInterface)
[error] (ScalaPokerEngine/compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

So it looks like I'm not allowed to run the Scala compiler? I'm not sure where Activator puts the Scala compiler and now I'm stuck.

Settings for the virtual machine (Vagrantfile and salt files) can be found here https://github.com/markisus/ActivatorVagrant/tree/scalapoker

Comment: I think it has something to do with synced folders. I'm not exactly sure how yet....

Comment: Windows will not allow deletion of files which have file names that are too long. I think somehow the compilation process is trying to delete some files and therefore the host machine is preventing it

Comment: have you tried changing the [mount permissions](http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/)? It might worth a try setting `dmode` and `fmode` to 777 just to test if that's the reason for your troubles.

Comment: @m1keil Tried and did not make any difference.

Comment: In my project compiling is fine but I'm seeing "java.io.fileNotFoundException:  <reallyLongFilePath> (operation not permitted)" error when I do "sbt assembly". My project resides in a Vagrant synced folder (i.e. /vagrant). My host is Windows 7, my guest Ubuntu Trusty 64bit. As @cbley points out the issue must be with the Windows filesystem. If I copy my project sources to a new non-synced folder on the Ubuntu guest and "sbt assembly" my project from there everything works as expected.<br/>Path to offending file on Windows host happens to be longer than 255 chars so that's likely the culprit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when your're using synced folders, the folder mounted inside the guest inherits the limitations of the hosts' underlying filesystem.

For one, it may not be possible to create symlinks.

Another common reason for such an error is that Windows filesystems do not allow concurrent access to a file by default. For example, you cannot delete a file which is still opened by another process (which is no problem on Linux).

On Windows, this is often the case with anti virus software which opens files with exclusive access in order to examine them, before they could be executed or loaded and cause damage to the system. Other processes (including the processes running inside the VM) receive errors when trying to access those files if the anti virus software is still analyzing them.

You could try to further inspect the problem on the host by running sysinternal's [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) during the compile phase. See which errors turn up for the files in the shared folder. Hint: use a starts-with filter for the path of files in order to include only events for the specific folder.

Inside the guest, you may run the activator within strace, e.g.:

```
$ strace -f -ocompile.log ./activator compile
```

Look into the `compile.log` file after the run for some clues.

Comment: I may not get time to try this out until after the bounty expires but in either case this sounds like a good general purpose thing to do for these types of situations, so I'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to change `target` directory of `sbt` inside `vagrant`:

```
$ sbt
sbt> set target:=file("/home/vagrant/orca-target/")
sbt> ;test;run
```